# How do I create a MSI-installer based on a set of files (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer

I have a large Visual Studio 2008 solution with several .NET-projects. When I do a Relase build I get a bunch of files (ddls, images, etc) and folders in a output folder. What I want to do now is to take those files and generate a MSI-installer package.

Then, when I run the MSI I want to copy the files and folder to the folder that the user specifies in the installer wizard.

What should I do to accomplish this? Could I run some script on post-build that generates a msi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this, a very popular open source installer:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: NSIS does not produce MSI-installer package.
If you want MSI-based installer, look at WiX toolset (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or create a setup project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ditto on NSIS isn't MSI based.  It also doesn't use MSBuild and integrate with Visual Studio.